# Auto Scroll to Top

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, autoscroll

I was able to get it to auto scroll to the top upon opening the app, but now it won't let you scroll anymore because of the `scrollView` forcefully keeping it at the top due to `willDisplay`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if info.count > 0 {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item:info.count - 1, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Where else can I put it?

Comment: You can remove this code from willDisplay method and put it below after reload the collection view so it scroll to top only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to achieve your needs. For animation, you just need to pass value true/false in animated of `scrollToRow` function.
Hope this will help you!

**To scroll top without animation**

```
func scrollToTopWithoutAnimation() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         if self.dataArray.count > 0 {
             let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
             collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
         }
     }
}
```

**To scroll top with animation**

```
func scrollToTopWithAnimation() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         if self.dataArray.count > 0 {
             let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
             collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Based off of @NikunjKumbhani  comment and your answer I was able to figure it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this after collectionView reload

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.scrollsToTop = true
 }
```